# Is it pythonic to assign a variable with if else statement?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is professional to assign a variable like this:

```
for i in range(m):
    incorrect += 1 if yhat[i]!=y[i] else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [it's been pointed out](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), statements like this are 100% Pythonic

```
a = FIRST_VALUE if CONDITION else OTHER_VALUE
```

The problem with your code is that it's not clear from the first glance what's happening when `yhat[i] == y[i]`:

- `incorrect = 0`
- or
- `incorrect += 0`?

Therefore I think your snippet in *not* Pythonic.

This is how I would have written that:

```
sum(x != y for x, y in zip(y, yhat))
```

*(I assume `len(y) == len(yhat) == m`, otherwise it doesn't make a lot of sense IMHO)*

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is.

> `conditional_expression ::=  or_test ["if" or_test "else" expression]`
> The expression x if C else y first evaluates the condition, C rather than x. If C is true, x is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and its value is returned.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) you can find some more details.